# Replacing the values of columns in text file

Tags: java

I have a file with different columns, the values of each column are string labels

```
col1    col2   col3
-----   -----  -----
A       WM     S2
B       JK     S3
C       ZO     S2
```

If I want to replace the values of each values to be numeric, I will have my table in the following format

```
col1    col2   col3
-----   -----  -----
0       3       6
1       4       7
2       5       6
```

How to write this in java?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `java.util.Scanner`, since `.next()` will treat numbers and text equally

```
final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("path_to_file"));
final List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();

try {
    // skip 2 first lines
    if (scanner.hasNextLine())
        scanner.nextLine();
    if (scanner.hasNextLine())
        scanner.nextLine();

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        final String[] line = new String[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3 && scanner.hasNext(); i++) {
            line[i] = scanner.next();
        }
        list.add(line);
        scanner.nextLine();
    }
} finally {
    scanner.close();
}

// the file content is in "list" variable now, so you can modify and save back to file
```

Comment: Thank you for replay , well ,what i meant by putting the two tables ,meaning that value A will be replaced with 0,and B will be replaced with 1,and this will go on till the last value in col3. which is S2 will be replaced with 6. Those tables are only example,the real number of rows and cols in unknown.i was thinking to read each col separately but it seems little bit hard to solve.i would appreciate it if you can help me

Answer (score -2):

As you don't know exactlly the number of rows

you do the following
- read all line (this will give you the number of rows)  rowsNo.
- you rewrite your table.

```
  for (int row=0; row<rowsNo; row++) {
  String rowStr = "";  
  for (int col=0; col<colsNo; col++)  
     rowStr += row+col*colsNo;
  System.out.println(rowStr);
 }
```